# No reputation loss for downvoting a question

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, voting

If I remember how SE works then downvoting costs you a small amount of reputation.

I recently downvoted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/83195/1721) on arqade, but my reputation hasn't dropped. Is it because the question was closed? Is there another reason?

I realize this is probably not a bug; rather, I don't understand how the system works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downvoting questions *used* to cost 1 reputation — but no more! Now it is indeed free.

See the relevant meta question: [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the link!