# Reputation loss for downvoting an answer

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, voting

I learned recently that [downvoting no longer costs reputation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5354/1721). But I found this in my reputation count today after voting on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84986/1721):

`-1     23:02  downvoted   Where can I find more Eridium?`

So what's the deal? Has reputation loss for downvoting been reintroduced?

Comment: Answer has been removed in case you go looking for it.

Comment: I saw this recently and was confused by the difference between `-2` and `-1` rep being lost through my reputation, and I couldn't figure out what was going on until now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downvoting *questions* does not cost any reputation.  Downvoting *answers* costs 1 reputation.  Its really not enough for it to be an issue though.

Comment: Aha, reading through the article again that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.